# Custom Field with autcomplete

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to build my own node reference custom field - I know several projects out there already do this, I am building this in order to learn... :)

My problem is the autocomplete path, it's not being triggered, I have checked the noderefcreate project and implemented my solution based on that project. But still; nothing is being triggered when I check firebug.

Here is my code:

```
function nodereference_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'nodereference_nodereference_form' => array(
      'label' => t('Node Reference Form'),
      'field types' => array('nodereference'),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      ),
      'settings' => array(
        'autocomplete_match' => 'contains',
        'autocomplete_path' => 'nodereference/autocomplete',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

function nodereference_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  if ($instance['widget']['type'] == 'nodereference_nodereference_form') {
    $widget = $instance['widget'];
    $settings = $widget['settings'];

    $element += array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['nid']) ? $items[$delta]['nid'] : NULL,
      '#autocomplete_path' => $instance['widget']['settings']['autocomplete_path'],
    );
  }

  return array('nid' => $element);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define method from where auto compete will take suggestions.
It can be done like this:

```
/**
 * implements hook_menu
 */
function your_module_name_menu() {
  $items['master_place/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_your_module_name_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('access example autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Auto complete method implementation
 * @param $string
 */
function _your_module_name_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();

  // Some fantasy DB table which holds cities
  $query = db_select('target_db_table', 'c');

  // Select rows that match the string
  $return = $query
    ->fields('c', array('target_column'))
    ->condition('c.target_column', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->execute();

  // add matches to $matches
  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $matches[$row->city] = check_plain($row->city);
  }

  // return for JS
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```